# Visualize output of each layer in theano Convolutional MLP

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, theano, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am reading [Convolutional Neural Networks tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#convolutional-neural-networks-lenet). I want to visualize output of each layer after model is trained. For example in function "evaluate_lenet5" I want to pass a instance (which is an image) to the network and see the output of each layer and the class that trained Neural Network set for the input. I thought it may be easy as doing a dot product on an image and Weight vector of each layer, but it did not work at all.

I have objects of each layer as :

```
# Reshape matrix of rasterized images of shape (batch_size, 28 * 28)
# to a 4D tensor, compatible with our LeNetConvPoolLayer
# (28, 28) is the size of MNIST images.
layer0_input = x.reshape((batch_size, 1, 28, 28))

# Construct the first convolutional pooling layer:
# filtering reduces the image size to (28-5+1 , 28-5+1) = (24, 24)
# maxpooling reduces this further to (24/2, 24/2) = (12, 12)
# 4D output tensor is thus of shape (batch_size, nkerns[0], 12, 12)
layer0 = LeNetConvPoolLayer(
    rng,
    input=layer0_input,
    image_shape=(batch_size, 1, 28, 28),
    filter_shape=(nkerns[0], 1, 5, 5),
    poolsize=(2, 2)
)

# Construct the second convolutional pooling layer
# filtering reduces the image size to (12-5+1, 12-5+1) = (8, 8)
# maxpooling reduces this further to (8/2, 8/2) = (4, 4)
# 4D output tensor is thus of shape (batch_size, nkerns[1], 4, 4)
layer1 = LeNetConvPoolLayer(
    rng,
    input=layer0.output,
    image_shape=(batch_size, nkerns[0], 12, 12),
    filter_shape=(nkerns[1], nkerns[0], 5, 5),
    poolsize=(2, 2)
)

# the HiddenLayer being fully-connected, it operates on 2D matrices of
# shape (batch_size, num_pixels) (i.e matrix of rasterized images).
# This will generate a matrix of shape (batch_size, nkerns[1] * 4 * 4),
# or (500, 50 * 4 * 4) = (500, 800) with the default values.
layer2_input = layer1.output.flatten(2)

# construct a fully-connected sigmoidal layer
layer2 = HiddenLayer(
    rng,
    input=layer2_input,
    n_in=nkerns[1] * 4 * 4,
    n_out=500,
    activation=T.tanh
)

# classify the values of the fully-connected sigmoidal layer
layer3 = LogisticRegression(input=layer2.output, n_in=500, n_out=10)
```

So can you suggest a way to visualize a sample of processing an image step by step after the neural network is trained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't so hard.
If you are using the same class definition of **LeNetConvPoolLayer** from the theano deep-learning tutorial, then you just need to compile a function with `x` as input and `[LayerObject].output` as output (where *LayerObject* can be any layer object like *layer0*, *layer1* etc. whichever layer you want to visualize.

> vis_layer1 = function([x], [layer1.output])

Pass a (or many) sample (exactly how you fed the input tensor while training) and you'll get the output of that particular layer for which your function is compiled for.

*Note:* In this way you will get the outputs in the exact same *shape* the model has used in calculation. However you can *reshape* it as you want by reshaping the output variable like `layer1.output.flatten(n)`.